# PHP DB Connection Variable Not Available On Include

Tags: php

I have a script like so, which includes a script in my model for handling image uploads. I then call a function in that file with addImage(), like so:

```
<?php
    include '../model/imageUploadHandler.php';

    $imgTitle = $_POST["image_title"];
    $imgDescr = $_POST["image_description"];
    $target_path = "../images/";
    $filename = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $target_path = $target_path . $filename;

    addImage($imgTitle, $imgDescr, $filename); 

?>
```

Then, in the imageUploadHandler.php, I write the function, which is called without a hitch:

```
<?php
    include('./db_conn.php');

    function addImage($title, $description, $target_path)
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO image_data (filename, title, description) VALUES ('$target_path','$title','$description')";
            echo $sql;

            if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            echo "1 record added";

            echo "The file " .  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
            echo $title;
            echo $description;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
    }
?>
```

I have included a "db_conn.php" script, such that I can include the db_conn.php wherever I need to connect to the databse. Here is the db_conn.php

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("","root","root", "image_info");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

The database is connected to and everything works well if I put the connection script directly inline without an include. However, when I try to include an external file (db_conn.php), then for some reason the $con variable is not available to my imageUploadHandler.php

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope problem. Unless passed in as an argument or declared `global` your connection will not be available in your function scope.

Comment: What would be the preferred or standard solution, then? Is declaring a global variable messy, or is that more or less the standard?

Comment: Globals should be used sparingly, can get difficult to manage. But there are some things like database connections that could be used globally within an application so using global makes sense. Some frameworks establish preferences on how it should be done within the framework, (Zend Framework uses a global registry), but its ultimately your choice.

Comment: So I've declared $con now as global $con, but it's still not available. Should I use the $_GLOBALS[] associative array?

Comment: You need to specify inside your function as `global $con`